# Generate column if other columns are equal

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame('ID'=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10), 
              'invoice'=c(24000, 21000, 25000, 21000, 26000, 27000,
               28000, 29000, 30000, 31000, 21000, 32000, 33000),
              'settle'=c(40000, 40000, 41000, 41000, 42000, 43000, 44000,
               45000, 46000, 47000, 47000, 48000, 49000), 
              'amount'=c(10, 10, 20, 10, 30, 10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 
               10, 30, 10), 
              'reason'=c(4, 5, 5, 5, 9, 4, 5, 9, 4, 5, 5, 15, 8))
```

And:

```
 df2 <- data.frame('ID'=c(1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12), 
              'invoice'=c(40000, 41000, 39000, 43000, 44000, 46000, 
               47000, 40000, 41000),
              'settle'=c(24000, 25000, 21000, 27000, 28000, 30000, 
               31000, 24000, 25000),
              'amount'=c(10, 20, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 10), 
              'reason'=c(4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4))
```

df1:

```
ID invoice settle amount reason
 1   24000  40000     10      4
 1   21000  40000     10      5
 2   25000  41000     20      5
 2   21000  41000     10      5
 3   26000  42000     30      9
 4   27000  43000     10      4
 5   28000  44000     20      5
 6   29000  45000     30      9
 7   30000  46000     10      4
 8   31000  47000     20      5
 8   21000  47000     10      5
 9   32000  48000     30     15
10   33000  49000     10      8
```

df2:

```
ID invoice settle amount reason
 1   40000  24000     10      4
 2   41000  25000     20      5
 2   39000  21000     20      5
 4   43000  27000     10      4
 5   44000  28000     20      5
 7   46000  30000     10      4 
 8   47000  31000     20      5
11   40000  24000     10      4
12   41000  25000     10      4
```

So I'd like to generate a dummy variable in **df1** from the following conditions:

```
if df1$ID == df2$ID
if df1$settle == df2$invoice
if df1$amount == df2$amount
if df1$reason == df2$reason
```

So if the conditions are met, my new column should be equal 1, else 0.

df1 with the new variable would look like this:

```
 ID invoice settle  amount reason  newvar
 1   24000  40000     10      4      1
 1   21000  40000     10      5      0
 2   25000  41000     20      5      1
 2   21000  41000     10      5      0
 3   26000  42000     30      9      0
 4   27000  43000     10      4      1
 5   28000  44000     20      5      1
 6   29000  45000     30      9      0
 7   30000  46000     10      4      1
 8   31000  47000     20      5      1
 8   21000  47000     10      5      0
 9   32000  48000     30     15      0
10   33000  49000     10      8      0
```

I've tried:

```
 df1$newvar <- ifelse(df1$ID == df2$ID & 
                      df1$settle == df2$invoice &
                      df1$amount == df2$amount &
                      df1$reason == df2$reason, 1, 0)
```

I get the warning message:

```
 "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"
```

So I gues an ifelse isn't possible since my two dataframes aren't of the same size (more ID's in df1 than in df2).

Can you help me solve this problem?

In SPSS or Stata I'd just use the IF-command, but R is pretty new to me!

**EDIT**

I've changed my test dataframes so they're more similar to the ones I work with.
I've also added a view of df1 with the new variable.

Comment: Perhaps you need `%in%` instead of `==`

Comment: With the given test data, you expect only 0s?

Comment: @Dennis: No, I've added a view of df1 as how I'd like the new variable to end up in my test data.

Answer (score 1):

the error is because your two data frames have different number of rows.

try to join both tables first by the criteria and then make your new column on df1.

```
df1<-left_join(df1,df2,by=c("ID"="ID","settle"="invoice","amount"="amount","reason"="reason"))
df1<-df1 %>% mutate(newvar=ifelse(is.na(settle.y),0,1)) %>%
             select(-settle.y)
```

Comment: hmm only works with the test data, not with my real data... I'll get back when I know what the difference is. 

The left-join doesn't work

Comment: Okay so I've solved it now, thanks to your help! 

I just made my new variable = 1 in my df2 before joining, and then it's there. The problem with my real data is that settle sometimes equals NA. 

But this works!